ExtJS Change color of checkbox, background, and border color
I need help changing the appearance of the checkboxes inside a grid panel. I want to have a white check mark, a blue background, and a gray border outline. I tried tinkering with the CSS but when changing the background color, it looks to bleed to outside the border and when changing the color of the check mark, the border color changes to the same color. Is there a way to do this or am I going to have to use an image column and have the check marks be images?

It wont be possible to tell anything without looking at your code. Please share the code for better understanding.

This is not an easy one. Maybe you can install "Sencha Themer" and give it a try with it. The solution depends as well on which theme you are using, each one has it's own styling rules for checkboxes.

You can try using ui. You can find more details in the sencha documentation. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.grid.column.Check.html#sass-mixins
@include checkcolumn-ui(
    $ui: 'my-checkbox',
    $background-color: #FFF,
    $color: #000
);

